# Как Преобразовать url

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте.
Использую на сайте такую конструкцию

```
RewriteRule (^[A-Za-z-]+)/([0-9]+.html$) /posts/post.php?category=$1/&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Url выглядит как пример

`example.com/catecory/id`

Хочу сделать просто `example.com/id` без category

Перепробовал кучу вариантов 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([\d]+)$ posts/post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает